# perl eval Use of uninitialized value declared in package

Tags: perl, scope, package, eval, lexical

can anyone explain to me why a variable that is declared in package can not be accessed by eval function unless it is used one time inside a sub?
(perl v5.16.3 MSWin32-x64-multi-thread ActiveState)

Package:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
package testPackage;
my $insertVar = "TEST";
sub testSub {
    my $class = shift;
    my $test = shift;
    eval '$test="'.$test.'";';
    return $test;
}
1;
```

Program:

```
use strict ;
use warnings ;
use testPackage ;
my $testVar = q[insertVar = ${insertVar}] ;
$testVar = testPackage->testSub( $testVar ) ;
print "$testVar\n" ;
```

Result when executing program:

> Use of uninitialized value $insertVar in concatenation (.) or string
>   at (eval 1)  line 1. insertVar =

Now if I use the variable inside testSub (by e.g. printing it):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
package testPackage;
my $insertVar = "TEST";
sub testSub {
    my $class = shift;
    my $test = shift;
    print $insertVar . "\n";
    eval '$test="'.$test.'";';
    return $test;
}
1;
```

Then the program runs exactly as I intended:

> TEST
>
> insertVar = TEST

Comment: Why on earth would you `eval` an assignment of a variable to set itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my` variables declared in a file (outside of curlies) go out of scope when the file finishes executing (before `require` and `use` return).

`$insertVar` will only continue to exist after the file has finished executing it if it's captured by a sub, and it will only be visible to the subs that capture it.

For efficiency reasons, subs capture the fewest variables possible. If the sub doesn't reference `$insertVar`, it won't capture it. Since your first `testSub` doesn't reference `$insertVar`, it doesn't capture it. Since `$insertVar` has gone out of scope by the time you call `testSub`, it's not available to `eval`. You should get the warning `Variable "$insertVar" is not available`, but for reasons unknown to me, it's issued for the specific code you used.

Your second `testSub` reference `$insertVar`, so `testSub` captures `$insertVar` and keeps it alive. Even though `$insertVar` has gone out of scope by the time you call `testSub`, it's available to `eval` since it was captured by the sub.

If you declare the variables using `our`, they'll be global package variables, and thus won't go out of scope, and they'll be available to `eval`.

```
>perl -wE"use strict; use warnings; { my $x = 'abc'; sub foo { $x } } say foo()"
abc

>perl -wE"use strict; use warnings; { my $x = 'abc'; sub foo { eval '$x' } } say foo()"
Variable "$x" is not available at (eval 1) line 2.
Use of uninitialized value in say at -e line 1.


>perl -wE"use strict; use warnings; { our $x = 'abc'; sub foo { eval '$x' } } say foo()"
abc
```

Comment: The correct answer would probably be to show this person how to access a package variable. It's an XY-problem.

Comment: @TLP, I did, though a proper template system should be used instead.

Comment: ikegami, Accepted and thanks for your clear answer, the part about how the variable is captured by the sub is the answer I was looking for. I just couldn't grasp what was happening here.
TLP, I am aware of 'our' and also that it makes the problem go away. I prefer the answer from ikegami because he explained to me how the life-cycle of a variable in a package works declared with 'my'.